# php laravel strict object casting

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, casting

I realized that laravel/eloquent does not save my model when I change a column with an object cast like this:

```
$original = '{"test": null}';
$new = '{"test": false}';
```

The reason is that attributes that are casted as an object are evaluated like this (to find out if the record is dirty) in HasAttributes.php::R1577:

```
 } elseif ($this->hasCast($key, ['object', 'collection'])) {
            return $this->castAttribute($key, $attribute) ==
                $this->castAttribute($key, $original);
```

I.e. it uses == to compare the two objects. So the problem can be recreated like this:

```
        $original = '{"test": null}';
        $new = '{"test": false}';

        $originalObject = json_decode($original, true);
        $newObject = json_decode($new, true);

        $original == $new; // false
        $originalObject == $newObject; // true <-- this is what laravel does and therefore thinks there was no change
        $originalObject === $newObject; // false <-- this is what I want (unless there is a reason not to do it)
```

Is there a reason that it compares using == instead of === ? And is there some way to force it to use strict comparison instead?

Answer (score 1):

#### Summary

The `object` cast will return an object instance. Strict comparisons on objects don't actually compare any values, only instance references. To get the comparison you're looking for, you'd need to switch to a `json` or `array` cast.

Of course, this means your variable will now be an associative array instead of an object, and your code would need to be updated accordingly.

#### Details

The `object` and `collection` casts will return an instance of an actual object (not an array). Laravel doesn't use strict comparison these casts because strict comparison works differently for objects than arrays:

- For arrays, strict comparison will return true if the two arrays have the same keys/values in the same order and type.
- For objects, the strict comparison doesn't compare any values, it will only return true of the two objects are actually the same instance of the same class.

Since strict comparison of objects compares against instances, the Laravel code you've shown would always return false, since you'd always be comparing two different object instances (even if they have the exact same data).

In order to get the comparison functionality you're looking for, you'd need to switch to using a `json` or `array` cast, which will convert your attribute to an associative array instead of an object. Laravel will use the strict comparison for associative arrays, which will compare the actual array data.

#### Example

As described, your example is not quite equivalent to what Laravel is doing. In your example code, you're passing `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()` (this is what Laravel does for the `json` and `array` casts), which will return associative arrays instead of objects. If you passed in `false` (this is what Laravel does for the `object` cast), you'll see your strict comparison fail.

Simple example:

```
[] === []; // true
(object)[] === (object)[]; // false

// or
json_decode('{}', true) === json_decode('{}', true); // true
json_decode('{}', false) === json_decode('{}', false); // false
```